# How to write a directive to compare two password in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, directive

How to write a directive to compare password in Ionic 2.
I have written a custom directive syntax which is fetching the current text field value,but i need to fetch the other text field value to compare, which is not possible through directive

```
*this is my custom directive
@Directive({
  selector: '[compare-password]', // Attribute selector
  host: {
        '(input)': 'ionChangesss($event)'
    }
})
export class ComparePasswordDirective {
  private elRef : ElementRef;
  constructor(public el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    this.elRef = el;

    }
     ionChangesss(eve) {
    }
```

Comment: Why not pass in the variable that needs to be compared to the directive to ? At change event chick if your ('var'  == $event.value) ?